# Change default column type in tabularray

Tags: tables, preamble, tabularray, column-width

Is it possible to set all `tblr` in the document to be `\linewidth` wide specifying the `X` column type by default?. This requires not mentioning the number of columns like it happens in `colspec`, as it varies for every `tblr`.

In this case, `colspec` could be used in certain columns where the default column type should be overriden.

For instance:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

% act here to specify a default column type

\SetTblrInner{
 width=\linewidth,
 %columns={X},
 baseline=T,
 hspan=even,
 vspan=even,
 stretch=1.3,
 row{1}={font=\bfseries},
 hline{1,Z}={0.6mm},
 hline{2}={0.3mm}
}

\begin{document}

 These tables should all have the same width without further modifications in the document body

 \begin{table}[!hb]
  \begin{tblr}{colspec={XX}}
   Head1 & Head2 \\
   Row21 & Row22 \\
   Row31 & Row32 \\
  \end{tblr}

  \begin{tblr}{}
   Head1 & Head2 \\
   Row21 & Row22Row22 \\
   Row31 & Row32 \\
  \end{tblr}

  \begin{tblr}{}
   Head1 & Head2 & Head3\\
   Row21 & Row22 & Row23 \\
   Row31 & Row32 & Row33 \\
   Row41 & Row42 & Row43 \\
  \end{tblr}

  \begin{tblr}{colspec={|l|X[r]|c|}}
   Head1 & Head2 & Head3\\
   Row21 & Row22 & Row23 \\
   Row31 & Row32 & Row33 \\
   Row41Row41 & Row42 & Row43 \\
  \end{tblr}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If a column's default width is `\linewidth`, how are tables with two columns, let alone tables with three or more columns, supposed to fit on a page?

Comment: @Mico `width` in `SetTblrInner` is referred to the whole `tblr`, not to single columns

Comment: I have opened [a discussion](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/discussions/408) related to this question in the official Github repository of the `tabularray` package.

Answer (score 1):

You've found the right option, `columns`. The last step is to feed it a column key-value list, like `co=1,bg=blue!20`, not an other column type like `X`.

By uncommenting the `columns={X},` line in OP's example and replacing it with `columns={co=1},`, you'll get

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

% act here to specify a default column type

\SetTblrInner{
 width=\linewidth,
 columns={co=1},
 baseline=T,
 hspan=even,
 vspan=even,
 stretch=1.3,
 row{1}={font=\bfseries},
 hline{1,Z}={0.6mm},
 hline{2}={0.3mm}
}

\begin{document}

 These tables should all have the same width without further modifications in the document body

 \begin{table}[!hb]
  \begin{tblr}{colspec={XX}}
   Head1 & Head2 \\
   Row21 & Row22 \\
   Row31 & Row32 \\
  \end{tblr}

  \begin{tblr}{}
   Head1 & Head2 \\
   Row21 & Row22Row22 \\
   Row31 & Row32 \\
  \end{tblr}

  \begin{tblr}{}
   Head1 & Head2 & Head3\\
   Row21 & Row22 & Row23 \\
   Row31 & Row32 & Row33 \\
   Row41 & Row42 & Row43 \\
  \end{tblr}

  \begin{tblr}{colspec={|l|X[r]|c|}}
   Head1 & Head2 & Head3\\
   Row21 & Row22 & Row23 \\
   Row31 & Row32 & Row33 \\
   Row41Row41 & Row42 & Row43 \\
  \end{tblr}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Unfortunately, because column types like `l` and `c` only set `halign` (to `l` and `c`, respectively) and don't reset `co` to its initial value `0` (which is altered by previous `columns={co=1}`), after setting `columns={co=1}`, a table with `colspec={|l|X[r]|c|}` will work like

```
colspec={|Q[l,co=1]|Q[r,co=1]|Q[c,co=1]|}
```

while what user may expect is

```
colspec={|Q[l,co=0]|Q[r,co=1]|Q[c,co=0]|}
```

One workaround is to explicitly use `colspec={|Q[l,co=0]|X[r]|Q[c,co=0]|}`.  (Currently there's no public interface to redefine an existing row/column type and column types setting horizontal alignment like `l` and `c` don't have an optional argument.)

Reported to `tabularray`, see https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/411.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

% act here to specify a default column type

\SetTblrInner{
 width=\linewidth,
 columns={co=1},
 baseline=T,
 hspan=even,
 vspan=even,
 stretch=1.3,
 row{1}={font=\bfseries},
 hline{1,Z}={0.6mm},
 hline{2}={0.3mm}
}

\def\testTblrColspec#1{
  \hspace*{-2em}\texttt{\UseName{tl_if_empty:nTF}{#1}{<empty>}{#1}}
  \par\medskip
  \begin{tblr}{#1}
   Head1 & Head2 & Head3\\
   Row21 & Row22 & Row23 \\
   Row31 & Row32 & Row33 \\
   Row41Row41 & Row42 & Row43 \\
  \end{tblr}
  \par\medskip
}

\begin{document}

\testTblrColspec{}
\testTblrColspec{colspec={|l|X[r]|c|}}
\testTblrColspec{colspec={|Q[l,co=0]|X[r]|Q[c,co=0]|}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/discussions/408#discussioncomment-6065333 I posted an experimental implementation for new option `columns type=<single column type>`, with which one can directly use `columns type=X`.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this seems to force a standard and homogeneous column width even if I specify `colspec` in columns where I don't want the default value. I would expect a specific `colspec` to override the preamble `columns={co=1}`. The same happens with `colspec={XXXXXXXXXXXX}` in preamble (rdrg109's workaround)

Comment: @Polizi8 See update in my answer.